# how to upgrade haskell-stack on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: package-management, updates, haskell

I am trying to upgrade my haskell installation as, as far as I understand, it is a very old version.

This is what I have tried:

```
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~$ stack --version
Version 0.1.10.0 x86_64
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~$ sudo apt upgrade haskell-stack
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
haskell-stack is already the newest version (0.1.10.0-1).
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~$ stack upgrade
Fetched package index.                                                                                    
Populated index cache.    
Cabal file warning in /tmp/stack-upgrade1153/stack-1.6.1/stack.cabal: Ignoring unknown section type: custom-setup
Cabal file warning in /tmp/stack-upgrade1153/stack-1.6.1/stack.cabal: Ignoring unknown section type: custom-setup
Invalid package ID: "array-0.5.1.1 base-4.9.1.0 binary-0.8.3.0 bytestring-0.10.8.1"
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu official repository has older version of the haskell-stack. Downlaod the latest one.
First remove stack

> sudo apt-get remove haskell-stack

then install using this which is the latest one

https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/#ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, so I removed the old version as described earlier:

```
sudo apt-get remove haskell-stack
```

then followed the "Linux (generic)" instructions at https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/#linux.

The `wget` command worked for me:

```
wget -qO- https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh
```

I had installed `gcc` via `sudo apt-get install gcc` as part of the original failed attempt to upgrade `stack`.